# Passing data to Glade UI before displaying

Tags: c, gtk, glade, gtk2

I'm using Glade GTK2 to build an about dialog (but this is extendable to any GtkWindow).
This is how I show it from my code:

```
GtkWidget *dialog_about = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "dialog_about"));
gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog_about));
gtk_widget_destroy(dialog_about);
```

Now, on Glade there is a label for showing the program version:

[image]

Is it possible to replace that "1.0" value with another one from my code before showing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `gtk_about_dialog_set_version`:

```
GtkWidget *dialog_about = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "dialog_about"));
gtk_about_dialog_set_version (dialog_about, MY_VERSION); // <-----
gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog_about));
gtk_widget_destroy(dialog_about);
```